# How to code a Setting View Controller like on Path Talk App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, storyboard

I would like to code a "settings" View Controller like on Path Talk App. It's a kind of parallax effect. Twitter has also the same effect.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T0T0.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1OJR.jpg

I started something with Storyboard but it doesn't really work : I use a TableViewController. Inside the TableView I have a View which contains 2 pictures (background and profile pictures), and then 3 Table View Section. The problem is when the user drag down, the picture goes down. It's not like on Path Talk App because on Path Talk App the images are fixed. They don't move down when the user drag down (see pictures).

So I found a library on GitHub : https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader which could help me, but before spending my day on the library, it would be nice to have your advices. Is that possible to do it easily with storyboard or the library is the best solution ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Don't add the header to the tableview but to its superview

Comment: I can't add the header to the superview. How did you do that ? [link](http://imgur.com/frAAD7M)

Comment: I guess it should be possible with a normal UIViewController. Add a UITableView to it and the header on top of it.

Comment: Finally this solution doesn't work because the image is fixed when the user scrolls down and when he scrolls up

Comment: Now I'm confused. I thought you wanted a fixed image?

Comment: Yes a fixed image when the user scrolls down and a non-fixed image when the user scrolls up... Yes, it's confusing... On Path Talk App, the View Controller seems to be a UITableViewController with an image at the top of the view (the background image). The VC has a fixed image when the user scrolls down to refresh the data and a non-fixed image when the user scrolls up. It's like on Twitter App except there is no effect on the background image (Twitter add a blur effect and a zoom effect when the user scrolls down).

Comment: Ok, cool: stick to the fixed image-approach and overwrite scrollViewDidScroll in your UITableViewDelegate. There you get the contentOffset and can move the image up by it when it is greater or equal than the initial offset. Do nothing when it is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a normal `UIViewController` in storyboard. Add a `UITableView` and i.e. an `UIImageView` to it. The tableView's frame should take the whole view, the imageView just the desired part in the top. 
Then make your viewController implement the `UITableViewDelegate` (and maybe `UITableViewDataSource` if you want to fill the table from it). In `viewDidLoad` set the delegates and an contentInset to respect the image as header:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.imageView.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` since a `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and move the image there depending on the scroll direction:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat imageY = -scrollView.contentOffset.y-self.tableView.contentInset.top;
    if(imageY>0)
        imageY = 0;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, imageY, self.view.bounds.size.width,     self.imageView.bounds.size.height);
}
```